# Partially download open street map in android

Tags: android, android-mapview, openstreetmap

I'm creating an application to allow user to use both online and offline map, online map i use Google map API, offline i use open street map (as Google map cannot be downloaded or cached according to their policy), how do I download the map partially ?

For example, now i have one destiny with coordinates x, y, how do I download map area around this coordinate and save on my device for later use, and later how do i load it out ?

Currently I can only display and zoom in - out with map view.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [mapsforge](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/), you can do offline maps for Android and even for the Desktop. It requires a lot less bandwidth compared to tiles with high zoom levels. Downside is that you'll have to create one map per area on your own servers like I do for graphhopper.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, do you have any detail steps on how to use to download and create map ?

Comment: @user1452954 you create maps with the mapsforge map writer and load it on android via their API. Should be simple. Just ask on their mailing list. http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapWriter important: make sure you use the correct version for osmosis. Only 0.40.1 will work I think!

Comment: @hgoebl thanks, feel free to join the mailing list in case you use it and have questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a raster map consisting of [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) or a vector map? Downloading large amounts of tiles from the official OSM servers is against their [tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy) because these servers run on funded resources. However you can [render your own tiles](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering), for example with [TileMill](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill) and [Maperitive](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive).

If you instead want to use a vector map then just go to the [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) and follow the  [Download](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Download) link on the front page.

For really small areas, say some streets, you can use the [regular API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6). For larger areas, say a city, you should try the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). And for anything larger the best is to use an [area or country extract](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). Afterwards you can use tools like [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis), [pbftoosm](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Pbftoosm) and [osmconvert](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert) to process the data further.

Note that you still need to render this raw map data to a vector map.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a (deep) look at the wiki of openstreetmap.org and search the web for "tiles offline osm".

And there is a project called **[osmdroid](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)**. It has a widget with most of the features of the Google Maps Widget. There is a offline tiles provider which can leverage downloaded tiles (cached and zip-files created with special tools).

One of the biggest problems in this area is that most tiles-server do not allow to download big areas of tiles for offline usage. If you use a tool like [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) you will get blocked by the tiles server and only download pictures which tell you "you are blocked".

So if you want to provide really big areas for your app-users with higher zoom levels (>14), you have a problem. But if you just provide a map for a small city, you could try to use one of the open tiles servers (AFAIK MapQuest is one of those with more liberate download policy) or buy a certain amount of tiles from the commercial providers (see wiki, I don't want to advertise here).

It would be nice if there was some kind of peer-to-peer file sharing of current maps. Because the license of OSM (at least how I understood it) says, that it's possible to sell maps based on OSM data, but those maps can be shared and published in any way.

If anybody finds a solution for sharing maps (without much costs of AWS/provider/cloudfront/...) this would be interesting for many Android App programmers. The advantage of `osmdroid` is that all installed apps can reuse the same maps.

Comment: I'm using osmaroid lib right now, i'm now stack on a few problems: 1. how do i download the map for a particular area (the region size won' matter, but zoom in level better be street level), what format shall i store as, and 2. how do i load it when i want to use and how do i put marker on it ?